# images are cropping automatically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, thumbnails, crop

i'm working on wordpress with themify parallax theme.there is a option in parallax theme setting to use header gallery.when i choose the images for gallery they are looking blurry.then i noticed that i have uploaded the image(bg04) of size 1024x619 and after checking the page with firebug its showing extra bg04-1024x536.jpg in every image.

Here are my media settings:

```
Thumbnail size  150x150

Medium size     300x300

Large size  1024x1024
```

Please guys help me on this.

Comment: I am not familiar of wordpress but lots of cms has regenerate thumbnails section. May be you miss regeneratig them?

Comment: @HddnTHA: no i dont want to regenerate them there was an option to select full size when we select the image for gallery but from WP 3.5 the option is not there.

Comment: Then you have to change something in css use firebug to find which class is effecting your image and find that class in your css file and change the values as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom size for thumbnail images

```
 add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
```

or use for getting original image size

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr )
```

where $size = 'full'

Answer (score 0):

You can something add this to your themes functions.php file to give it custom sizes.

```
/* Add Post Thumbnails */
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support'  ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 110, 96, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
    add_image_size( 'post-image', 350, 350, TRUE ); // Post image
    add_image_size( 'news-listing', 140, 140, TRUE ); // News Listing image
    add_image_size( 'slider_image', 1070, 378, TRUE ); // Slider image
}
```

And then to grab the specific sizes you use

```
$src = grab_featured_img_url('slider-image');
```

(Sorry if you already knew how to do that, just covering all bases :) )

If you dont want wordpress to crop your images for you, and you've already added them, maybe consider this plugin

https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/manual-image-crop

That will help you set specific sizes and allow you to manually crop images that are done a bit off.

Comment: the linked plugin doesn't work anymore  - seems abandoned.